# How to make Spring IoC container available through out project

Tags: spring

I feel stupid to even ask for this but I spent days looking for the answer and I'm still with nothing.

I wanna include simple Spring IoC container in my project. All I want it to do is to allow me Injecting/Autowiring some reusable objects in other classes. What I've done so far looks like this:

[-> Project structure here <-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M9YF.png)

Configuration code:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Random;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Random rand() {
        return new Random(42);
    }

    @Bean
    public String string() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

Main class code:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    @Autowired
    Random rand;

    @Autowired
    String string;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // workflow

        Main main = new Main();
        System.out.println(main.string);
    }
}
```

AnotherClass code:

```
package com.example.deeperpackage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.Random;

public class AnotherClass {

    @Autowired
    Random rand;

    @Autowired
    String string;

    public void methodToBeCalled() {
        // TODO
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}
```

How can I make these @Autowired annotations work? Do I have to instantiate container in every single class in which I want to autowire components? I've seen in work a oracle app which used Spring and @Inject to distribute objects to numerous classes and there was no container logic in any class available for me. Just fields with @Inject annotation. How to achieve that?

Comment: Simply add the annotation @Component on the classes you want to inject :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the annotation @Component on the classes you want to inject :

```
@Component
public class AnotherClass {
...
}
```

But you cannot inject static attributes and when you do new Main(), no Spring context is being created. If you use Spring Boot, you should look at how to write a main with it.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: I do note mean to inject AnotherClass. I wanna inject some stuff defined in config (like logger, or hibernate factories) so I cannot even add @Component to these.

AnotherClass will be instantiated just like AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass(); I need components to be put inside it just like inside main.

Comment: I guess you can do is init a new Spring context and get the beans created inside :
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(<out-main-config-class>.class);

Comment: I know that, the context was initialized but I still got NullPointerException. What is more, will I have to do it in every class I wanna extract something? (I counted on single initialization in Main class and Autowiring in the rest of the project freely)

Comment: Autowired annotations will not work outside a class inited by spring. Spring cannot guess you instantiated an Object with a new.

Comment: So basically I have to initialize context in Main class and every further class in which I wanna use @Autowire register as components and instantiate them through spring?

Comment: Yes, this is how spring works. Once the context is initialized, you hardly ever use a class outiside the context. In a jee server, the spring context is initialized via a Servlet that loads with the server.